# Change visibility of markers on a google map taking into account respective attributes

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a google map on my website that receives all the marker information through makethemap.php
Its working all fine and the map is correctly generated. However, I don't know how to change the visibility of the marker taking into consideration the price variable.

Lets say, when the user clicks on the given (below) radio-button I want all markers with a price variable lower than 1200 to disappear.

```
 function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.600, -58.400),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    scrollwheel: false,
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;


  downloadUrl("makethemap.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var idofobject = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
      var price = markers[i].getAttribute("price")
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));

      var html = 'each marker has an individual infotext'
      marker= new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,

      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
          });
}





function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}


<input type="radio" name="1200" value="male">Places above $1200<br>
```

I was able to do it before I loaded the map over php. 
Any help greatly appreciated. This is bothering me for quite some time now!

Comment: You're going to need to add logic that checks the price of the marker and then based on the price, hides the markers you don't want displayed OR only load the ones you do want.

Comment: Do you want to do it client(javascript) OR client(PHP)?

Comment: client(javascript) @davidstrachan